# Updating Previous Owner field on Case object

Tags: apex, case, custom-field, trigger

I have a custom field called `Previous_Owner__c` on the standard `Case` object. Every time the `Owner` is changed, I need to update this field with the previous owner's value. I have written a `before update` trigger to handle this requirement. Do I need to bulkify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any `SOQL` or `DML`, so there is basically nothing to bulkify. The basic structure should be:

```
for (Case newRecord : trigger.new)
{
    Case oldRecord = trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id);
    if (newRecord.OwnerId != oldRecord.Id)
        newRecord.Previous_Owner__c = oldRecord.OwnerId;
}
```

Make sure you do not try to apply such logic in a `before insert` trigger, only `before update`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! thats what I thought but wanted to be double sure... My trigger is exactly on your lines

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with configuration also.Create a workflow rule with criteria created & every time edited and select formula like

IF( (ISCHANGED( OwnerId )) , true, false)

And do a field update like

PRIORVALUE(OwnerId)

And is easy to maintain.But you can't get the name of the owner here.

I think it resolves your problem @Maneesh Gupta