# Store original Case-Queue when ownership changes

Tags: case, ownership, queue

How can we store the case's original queue when the case's ownership changes?

We want to have views like `all cases in queue=X or original-queue=X` to also display cases that are actually currently assigned to specific users but still belong to the queue's "topic"

Comment: Sounds like this is 'information' that you'd probably want to store on the case itself.

Comment: you mean as a custom field that is not named OriginalQueue but more like Topic?

Comment: That sounds very logical

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a custom field on the case that shows the previous owner. However, I think you would have to populate the field using an apex trigger.

Maybe this can help: [Updating Previous Owner field on Case object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119307/updating-previous-owner-field-on-case-object)

If you only want to reference Queues, you may have to add some logic with a list of your existing queues.